# Explorer dies silently and in unexpected ways

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, windows-explorer, crash

I regularly get an Application error followed by a Windows Error Reporting event when I've started explorer multiple times to copy or move data. The running action windows stay open, thus I can easily re-open explorer again by clicking the "From" and "To" links, but it's still annoying.
The error:

```
Faulting application name: explorer.exe, version: 6.2.9200.16433, time
stamp: 0x50763312 
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16579, time stamp: 0x51637f77
Exception code: 0xc0000374 
Fault offset: 0x00000000000ebd59 
Faulting process id: 0x2b58 
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce807d7eba15ac 
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\explorer.exe 
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll 
Report Id: bd4a60ea-ec70-11e2-be77-0024e8305414 
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

The report:

```
Fault bucket 108782508, type 4 
Event Name: APPCRASH 
Response: Not available 
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature: 
P1: explorer.exe 
P2: 6.2.9200.16433 
P3: 50763312
P4: StackHash_5c5e 
P5: 6.2.9200.16579 
P6: 51637f77 
P7: c0000374 
P8: PCH_C1_FROM_ntdll+0x0000000000002C2A 
P9:  
P10: 

Attached files:
C:\Users\Wim\AppData\Local\Temp\WER1F0E.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\Wim\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_explorer.exe_c20d52f176ca6d4081a647b4054c9ace6f9b_2b3f21ad

Analysis symbol:  
Rechecking for solution: 0 
Report Id: bd4a60ea-ec70-11e2-be77-0024e8305414 
Report Status: 16 
Hashed bucket: c39255172faabea75e27be696c1c2f6e
```

The XML file mentioned in the report doesn't exist. The WER file does, and I've put it on [my website](http://wimtenbrink.nl/Report.wer.txt). Explorer loads a lot of modules, but tells me the problem is ntdll.dll, which is one of those you can't disable...

I could, of course, start everything in 'Safe Mode', try to discover which module generates this problem and then just not use it. But this takes a lot of time to solve something that just annoys me. Often, Explorer will just work fine for hours, but when I'm having a 20+ copy/move actions, explorer itself just gives up sometimes...
So, does anyone know a **quick** fix?

Comment: I need a dump file. Follow the steps from here and upload the dump: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Comment: Done. But I can't predict the next crash. Right now, it seems reliable again.